# Javascript: How come comparison operators are evaluated before postfix increment operator?

Tags: javascript

[According to this precedence table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) incrementing has a high priority than comparison operators. And yet, when I increment and compare in the same expression, the comparison is evaluated first. Why is this?

```
var i = 0, k = 0;
console.log(i === k);
>true
console.log(i++ === k);
>true
>false
```

How come comparison operators are evaluated before postfix increment operator?

Answer (score 5):

the postfix increment is indeed evaluated first, before the comparison, and so the preference table is correct. But the value of the postfix increment evaluation is not the incremented value, it's the value before incrementing. This is, as Adam pointed out, the intended behaviour of postfix increment.

Comment: Thanks - I was struggling to explain why the table was correct but couldn't quite get there.  Thanks +1

Answer (score 3):

That's how the post-increment operator works.  It uses the variable in the expression, and then increments.  If you want the increment to happen first, you would use the pre-increment operator like this:

```
console.log(++i === k);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing precedence with functionality. Postfix increment operator does have higher precedence than prefix increment operator and as such it is processed first. It is the functionality of prefix increment operator that determine that it should increment after returning. It is not a matter of of precedence.